# How to set build command for "saving current file" then run "octave script" in geany text editor?

Tags: save, octave, overwrite, geany

I am running octave scripts in geany text editor.
To execute the octave command, I have custom build command

```
Execute: octave -q "%f"
```

But I want to create a custom build command like:

```
save_this_file; octave -q "%f"
```

or, `save_this_file; octave -q --persist "%f"`

so, that first it will save the file,and then execute the octave script.

Each time I have to save the file first(Ctrl S) and then execute (F5),
instead it would be easier if we don't have to save the file each time.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for extra Ctrl+s. F5 is saving the file in default before running it.

Comment: Oh yes, it works, i used to save the file each time before executing it, now F5 works both works at the same time!